# In modern Yu-Gi-Oh! TCG PSCT, how are effects ordered?

Tags: yu-gi-oh, terminology, custom-game-pieces

Yu-Gi-Oh! cards often have several effects (and other sentences) in their card texts.  For example, Amazoness Onslaught and Toy Magician each have three effects...

> Once per turn, during the Battle Phase: You can Special Summon 1 "Amazoness" monster from your hand, and if you do, it gains 500 ATK until the end of this turn (even if this card leaves the field). After damage calculation, if your "Amazoness" monster battled an opponent's monster while this card is already face-up in your Spell & Trap Zone: You can banish that opponent's monster. If this card on the field is destroyed and sent to the GY: You can target 1 "Amazoness" monster in your GY; Special Summon it.

> You can Set this card from your hand to your Spell & Trap Zone as a Spell. During the End Phase, if this Set card in your Spell & Trap Zone was destroyed by an opponent's card effect and sent to the GY this turn: Special Summon this card. If this card is Flip Summoned: Destroy Spells and Traps on the field, equal to the number of "Toy Magicians" on the field.

I am curious as to how such effects are sequenced.  Some clear patterns do emerge, i.e., restrictions on Summoning a monster go as near the beginning of that monster's card text as is practical, and "When this card is Summoned" Trigger Effects tend to be listed before "When this card is sent to the GY" Trigger Effects.  However, there is at least some apparent inconsistency, i.e., "You can only control 1 [card name]" can appear near the beginning or end of a card's text, even considering only the last five years of PSCT.

Is there a list of what principles do exist for creating card text which is sequenced as closely to official PSCT as possible?